# Determining "% slopes" of lines

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

My previous posts were unsuccessful.  I need help from a math person so I can write a c#.net application.  I know c#.net but my math skills aren't as strong, which is why I'm here.

I need the formulas to solve for the %-slopes (x and y) in the attached image.

My Scenario:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "X in % slope"?

Comment: slopes are based on a flat surface. 45-degrees = 1:1 = 100%.  When I rotate everything, based on the 1% slope shown on my image...what is the formula to solve the new slope?

Comment: If your previous posts were unsuccessful the course of action is *not* to make a new user and post new questions, but to **improve** the previous posts.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I found someone who was able to offer actual useful input.

Comment: the name X and Y are not correct in the picture. This is the only real problem.

Comment: For your picture, it seems that your 1% of slope would be negative. What you have to do is draw a rectangular coordinate system and then the angles of $45^{\circ}$ would be equal to $44^{\circ}$ or $43^{\circ}$ according to the 1% considered for your line. After this you simply proceed whithout difficulty.

Comment: (+1, and Welcome to Math.SE!) If you're willing, a more descriptive title, such as "Finding slopes of lines as percents", will help future users with similar questions find your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a straight line of equation y =a x +b, a = tan (theta)

where theta is the angle between the horizontal axis and the line.

From your picture, theta=46 degree or theta=44 degree.

You multiply the a value by 100 to have it in %

Comment: Hi Claudeh5...first thank you!!! You are the only person who understood what i was looking for so far.  This matches what I drew in my cad application, though I'm a bit confused because I think you are using standard math designations for triangles (a,x,y,b), instead of the x/y I show on my sketch. Am I correct?

Comment: What is not correct in your picture is the names X and Y. You must have two axis, X is the horizontal axis and Y the vertical axis. So all the coordinates are clearly defined.

Comment: Thanks Claudeh...i was just using those to represent the values I needed to get....didn't intend to mean anything particular (like x/y axis)

Comment: yes in the form a = tan(theta) and in %, the formula is a =100 tan(theta)

Comment: Claudeh I want to have your babies... I LOVE PEOPLE WHO KNOW WHAT I NEED bahahaha :)  Thank you soooooooo much...it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Dtan}{\tan^{\circ}}$Mathematicians are accustomed to expressing slopes of lines as tangents of angles, but percents are relatively unfamiliar nowadays. (I've only known civil engineers to use percents as slopes "in the wild", for road grades.)

If we measure angles counterclockwise (the standard mathematical convention), your "line at $1$%" makes an angle $\theta_{0} = \frac{180}{\pi}\arctan(-0.01)$ in degrees from rightward horizontal. Your line segments therefore make respective angles of $\theta_{0} - 45$ and $\theta_{0} + 45$; their slopes as percentages are
$$
100\Dtan(\theta_{0} \pm 45)
  = 100 \frac{\Dtan \theta_{0} \pm \Dtan 45}{1 \mp \Dtan \theta_{0} \Dtan 45}
  = 100 \frac{-0.01 \pm 1}{1 \pm 0.01},
$$
or $-\dfrac{101}{0.99} = -102.\overline{02}$ and $\dfrac{99}{1.01} = 98.\overline{0198}$.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you are correct, this was for a civil application.